# Why would an IIS ASP.Net Deployment change currency & date formats?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, modernizr

We have deployed an identical build with identical deployment methods to three virtual machines, two of which run as expected - the other does not.

The working boxes are running Windows Server 2019 with IIS 10, and Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5.
The bugged box is running Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5.

This issue is that we expect dates to be displayed as dd/mm/yyyy but we are seeing mm/dd/yyyy, and currencies are expected to be prefixed with '£' but are prefixed with '$'.

We do have a custom configuration implementation running though there are no discrepancies between the settings.

The issue is almost definitely environmental due to the reproduction difficulties on different boxes but the previous version did not display this issue.

Website: .Net Framework 4.6.1, AspNet MVC,
Javascript Libraries: JQuery 1.10, JQueryUI 1.10.3, and Modernizr 2.6.2.

Comment: are the servers configured with the same locale? my first guess would be the working ones are en-gb and the wrong one en-us

Comment: This is why you should always be explicit with your date formatting and not rely on whatever the default for the system is.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I was just investigating this. I have copied this code onto the boxes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/set-current-culture#code-try-1. Both come back with the following: "Current Culture is English (United Kingdom)".

Comment: @DavidG Certainly an oversight with this particular system design, however there are cases when you can rely on setting it in a particular instance's config file. Say if you have regional deployments.

Comment: @Krist0f Can you share the code where you are display the `$` data?

Comment: @Rahatur We use a line of code that reads somewhat like this: Amount.ToString("c2");. My understanding of this is that it uses the OS culture to apply the correct symbol, and rounds the value to two decimal places. Above you can read I have checked the culture on the machines and it is as expected.

Comment: Please check if the settings of .NET Globalization on iis are the same. [.NET Globalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831368(v=ws.11)).

Comment: @samwu Yes they are the same.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.